# Drop shadow on a custom TableViewCell

Tags: xcode, cocoa, swift

I'm trying to give my own `UITableViewCell` a drop shadow. I see there are 2 ways. The first one (which I would prefer) is to use the *User Defined Runtime Attributes* in the *Identity Inspector*:

[image]

1 question here: I read I need to add `layer.shadowOffset`, but what `Type` would I use there?

The second method would be to do it programatically

```
let rgb: CGColorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
let black: [CGFloat]   = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

cell.layer.shadowColor = CGColorCreate(rgb, black)
cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
cell.layer.shadowRadius = 10;
cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-2, 7)
```

both versions don't work. The shadow just doesn't show. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that the shadow is drawn outside the cell on what is behind it. But you can't see that because the next cell covers it! So you have no way of knowing whether the shadow is being drawn or not.

Another problem is that the cell may have `clipsToBounds` set to `true`. Thus the shadow is never drawn because it is outside the bounds of the cell.

One easy way to do what you're after is to draw the shadow manually *inside* the cell (e.g. as the shadow of a subview of the cell's content view).

Comment: Thank you! The `masksToBounds` was it. One more question: Do you know how to set the `cell.layer.shadowOffset` in the *User Defined Runtime Attributes*? Ie. what type that would be?

Comment: It wouldn't be any type; things like CGPoint and CGSize are not objects, and you can't configure an NSValue wrapper here. But you can define a cell subclass with custom properties so that you can break the offset into two numbers.

Comment: Previous comment is incorrect...Here's what you can define in user defined attributes: Boolean, Number Types, Localized String, CGPoint, CGSize, CGRect, NSRange, UIColor, UIImage, & nil. For shadowOffset, you would use CGSize.